# Sinch storing messages

Tags: java, android, sinch

In Sinch documentation for Android there's:

> Note: Messages are stored in the backend for 30 days before being removed. If the recipient
>   has not started the app and downloaded the message history within this time frame, the
>   message will be lost and no notification will be received.

How storing messages is handled by Sinch or how should it be done to download the message history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By logging in as the user, any unseen message on that device will automatically be downloaded. At the moment there is no public API to get the message history.

Comment: Is this possible for the Javascript API?

Answer (score 1):

if you follow Sinch Tutorial using Parse as back-end to store messages you can retrieve those messages using parse queries. 
Follow [Sinch Android instant messenger](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/) Tutorial for details.